# How to avoid LinkedIn automatically connecting to my Gmail account

Tags: gmail, linkedin

I recently opened a profile on LinkedIn and gave it access to my Gmail account. The result was that it sent a message of invitation to all my contacts!

Now I have removed all the unwanted invitations but what I want know is:

**What do I have to do to avoid re-connecting it to my Gmail account in future?**

Answer (score 2):

This site looks like it has the answer:
http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Authorized-Websites-in-Google

If you go to the Personal Settings Page as suggested, you should be able to see exactly what websites or apps have been authorized to use your account. It certainly looks like this is what happened in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that Linkedin has access to hundreds of contacts over many years that would be in one of my gmail accounts, but I never gave Linkedin permission to access my Gmail or ever send emails. However, my mobile device has a Linkedin app, although I have almost never logged into it! The mobile device itself has Gmail permissions, by way of necessity to use the Android apps on my phone with a Gmail account! ... This means that if the Linkedin App 'requires' permissions to my Gmail account, in my phone, it gets them!!!

The only solution would be to uninstall the Linkedin app from any Gmail-authorised mobile device!

I must admit, it is *interesting* seeing pictures and professional permissions of people I knew from years ago, or may have only saved their email address some years ago, but never, or only once emailed, but aside from that, it makes Linkedin compete with Facebook as the most complete NSA/CIA/OWG trojan on the planet.

Comment: In the Linkedin app info I see:
"precise location
 modify your contacts
 read call log
 read your contacts
 write call log
 read calendar events plus confidential information
 read your own contact card"
and a litany of additional scary powers! Uninstalling it now, but first deleting the app data.